# Getting Socket error when running test ng program through eclipse

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: 
socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(UnknownSource)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.SerializedMessageSender.sendMessage(SerializedMessageSender.java:21)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:44)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestStart(RemoteTestListener.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1832)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1807)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at
```

Comment: Do the tests run fine outside Eclipse (if you start them with `mvn test`, for example)? Are you behind a proxy? That may have something to do with it

Comment: Yes, i am behind proxy, using corporate network. Any way to get out of this as i testng also not showing result

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the proxy in Eclipse, if you have not already done it.

In Eclipse, go to the Window menu, then Preferences. Type "proxy" in the search text box. Choose Network Connections. There you can set the proxy.

On the other side, in order to set the proxy for a standalone Maven installation, you have to edit the `settings.xml` file in `<maven-home>/conf`. Edit the `proxies` element filling all the data you need:

```
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |  -->

    <proxy>
      <id>httpProxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>172.16.63.254</host>
      <port>3128</port>
    </proxy> 

    <proxy>
      <id>httpsProxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>172.16.63.254</host>
      <port>3128</port>
    </proxy>

      <!--<username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>-->
  </proxies>
```